# Why does DSolve show result as {}?

Tags: differential-equations

Using the following code, I get as an output: `{}`.
Does anyone know what does that means?

```
y1'[x]=a*y1[x]^2;
y2'[x]=b*y2[x]*(y2[x]-c*y1[x]);
(y2[x]/y1[x])'=b*y2[x]*(y2[x]/y1[x]-(c+a/b));

DSolve[{y1'[x]==0,(y2[x]/y1[x])'==0},{y1[x],y2[x]},x]
```

Comment: it is a little hard to know what is it you are solving. You seem to have an ode in $y1'$ and ode in $y2'$, right? Then you have something on the third line, which I can't make what it is. It is better to look at some examples in help to see correct syntax of writing ode. That is not how they are written.  For example, the first one should be `ode1=y1'[x]== a*y1[x]^2;`. Also watch out for spaces. You have `by2[x]` this should be `b*y2[x]` Basically you have many basic syntax errors in your code.

Answer (score 1):

- `(y2[x]/y1[x])'` should be `D[y2[x]/y1[x], x]` since `'` or `Derivative[1]` only work for pure function.
- Maybe you want to solve `a,b,c`.

```
sol = DSolve[{y1'[x] == a*y1[x]^2, 
   y2'[x] == b*y2[x]*(y2[x] - c*y1[x])}, {y1, y2}, x]
Solve[D[y2[x]/y1[x], x] == 0 /. sol[[1]]]
```

[image]

and when we add `D[y1[x], x] == 0`,

```
Reduce[{D[y1[x], x] == 0 /. sol[[1]], 
  D[y2[x]/y1[x], x] == 0 /. sol[[1]]}]
```

> `False`.

It means that there are no `a,b,c` satisfied the original equations.